# php readfile() and fopen() damaged/corrupt download

Tags: php, download, fopen, readfile, corrupt

Long time lurker first time poster,

Im done pulling my hair out over this, so i figured i would swallow the pride and ask the experts,
I have read in excess of 20 similar issues here and tried all fixes solutions but im getting the same results.

Im using PHP for users to download items, however i have tried readfile and fopen but EVERY download is corrupt, sometimes 0 in size other times the correct(ish) size, But always damaged or corrupt

Can someone take a peek at this code and tell me whats wrong with it, ive scoured it so many times now im probably just missing something rediculously simple, ..... as usual

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(contents of /loap.php can be shown if needed)

EDIT : Resolved
**Just a quick update for anyone who stumbled across this, I managed to get this working ...... I had tried many different variations of certain commands, but it seems i had missed trying with "ob_clean()" and "ob_end_flush()" with fopen(),
 .. It did the trick and as i expected it was a simple fix Thanks for the help Twisty, you poked at my inspiration ;)**

```html
<?php 
require_once('../secura/load.php');

function get_remote_file_size($url, $readable = true){
   $parsed = parse_url($url);
   $host = $parsed["host"];
   $fp = @fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 20);
   if(!$fp) return false;
   else {
       @fputs($fp, "HEAD $url HTTP/1.1\r\n");
       @fputs($fp, "HOST: $host\r\n");
       @fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
       $headers = "";
       while(!@feof($fp))$headers .= @fgets ($fp, 128);
   }
   @fclose ($fp);
   $return = false;
   $arr_headers = explode("\n", $headers);
   foreach($arr_headers as $header) {
    $s = "Content-Length: ";
       if(substr(strtolower ($header), 0, strlen($s)) == strtolower($s)) {
           $return = trim(substr($header, strlen($s)));
           break;
       }
   }
   
   return $return;
}

function get_ext($name)

{

 $fn = get_basename($name);

 return (strpos($fn, '.') ? strtolower(substr(strrchr($fn, '.'), 1)) : '');

}
function get_basename($name)



{

 return basename(str_replace('\\', '/', $name));

}

function get_filesize_unit($size)



{

 $size = max(0, $size);

 static $u = array('&nbsp;B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB');

 for ($i=0; $size >= 1024 && $i < 4; $i++)

 {

  $size /= 1024;

 }

 return number_format($size, 1).' '.$u[$i];

}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function find_mime_type($ext)

{

 static $mime_types = array(

  'application/andrew-inset' => array('ez'),

  'application/mac-binhex40' => array('hqx'),

  'application/mac-compactpro' => array('cpt'),

  'application/mathml+xml' => array('mathml'),

  'application/msword' => array('doc'),

  'application/octet-stream' => array('bin', 'dms', 'lha',

   'lzh', 'exe', 'class', 'so', 'dll', 'dmg'),

  'application/oda' => array('oda'),

  'application/ogg' => array('ogg'),

  'application/pdf' => array('pdf'),

  'application/postscript' => array('ai', 'eps', 'ps'),

  'application/rdf+xml' => array('rdf'),

  'application/smil' => array('smi', 'smil'),

  'application/srgs' => array('gram'),

  'application/srgs+xml' => array('grxml'),

  'application/vnd.mif' => array('mif'),

  'application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml' => array('xul'),

  'application/vnd.ms-excel' => array('xls'),

  'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' => array('ppt'),

  'application/vnd.wap.wbxml' => array('wbxml'),

  'application/vnd.wap.wmlc' => array('wmlc'),

  'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc' => array('wmlsc'),

  'application/voicexml+xml' => array('vxml'),

  'application/x-bcpio' => array('bcpio'),

  'application/x-cdlink' => array('vcd'),

  'application/x-chess-pgn' => array('pgn'),

  'application/x-cpio' => array('cpio'),

  'application/x-csh' => array('csh'),

  'application/x-director' => array('dcr', 'dir', 'dxr'),

  'application/x-dvi' => array('dvi'),

  'application/x-futuresplash' => array('spl'),

  'application/x-gtar' => array('gtar'),

  'application/x-hdf' => array('hdf'),

  'application/x-javascript' => array('js'),

  'application/x-koan' => array('skp', 'skd', 'skt', 'skm'),

  'application/x-latex' => array('latex'),

  'application/x-netcdf' => array('nc', 'cdf'),

  'application/x-sh' => array('sh'),

  'application/x-shar' => array('shar'),

  'application/x-shockwave-flash' => array('swf'),

  'application/x-stuffit' => array('sit'),

  'application/x-sv4cpio' => array('sv4cpio'),

  'application/x-sv4crc' => array('sv4crc'),

  'application/x-tar' => array('tar'),

  'application/x-tcl' => array('tcl'),

  'application/x-tex' => array('tex'),

  'application/x-texinfo' => array('texinfo', 'texi'),

  'application/x-troff' => array('t', 'tr', 'roff'),

  'application/x-troff-man' => array('man'),

  'application/x-troff-me' => array('me'),

  'application/x-troff-ms' => array('ms'),

  'application/x-ustar' => array('ustar'),

  'application/x-wais-source' => array('src'),

  'application/xhtml+xml' => array('xhtml', 'xht'),

  'application/xslt+xml' => array('xslt'),

  'application/xml' => array('xml', 'xsl'),

  'application/xml-dtd' => array('dtd'),

  'application/zip' => array('zip'),

  'audio/basic' => array('au', 'snd'),

  'audio/midi' => array('mid', 'midi', 'kar'),

  'audio/mpeg' => array('mpga', 'mp2', 'mp3'),

  'audio/x-aiff' => array('aif', 'aiff', 'aifc'),

  'audio/x-mpegurl' => array('m3u'),

  'audio/x-pn-realaudio' => array('ram', 'ra'),

  'application/vnd.rn-realmedia' => array('rm'),

  'audio/x-wav' => array('wav'),

  'chemical/x-pdb' => array('pdb'),

  'chemical/x-xyz' => array('xyz'),

  'image/bmp' => array('bmp'),

  'image/cgm' => array('cgm'),

  'image/gif' => array('gif'),

  'image/ief' => array('ief'),

  'image/jpeg' => array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'jpe'),

  'image/png' => array('png'),

  'image/svg+xml' => array('svg'),

  'image/tiff' => array('tiff', 'tif'),

  'image/vnd.djvu' => array('djvu', 'djv'),

  'image/vnd.wap.wbmp' => array('wbmp'),

  'image/x-cmu-raster' => array('ras'),

  'image/x-icon' => array('ico'),

  'image/x-portable-anymap' => array('pnm'),

  'image/x-portable-bitmap' => array('pbm'),

  'image/x-portable-graymap' => array('pgm'),

  'image/x-portable-pixmap' => array('ppm'),

  'image/x-rgb' => array('rgb'),

  'image/x-xbitmap' => array('xbm'),

  'image/x-xpixmap' => array('xpm'),

  'image/x-xwindowdump' => array('xwd'),

  'model/iges' => array('igs', 'iges'),

  'model/mesh' => array('msh', 'mesh', 'silo'),

  'model/vrml' => array('wrl', 'vrml'),

  'text/calendar' => array('ics', 'ifb'),

  'text/css' => array('css'),

  'text/html' => array('html', 'htm'),

  'text/plain' => array('asc', 'txt'),

  'text/richtext' => array('rtx'),

  'text/rtf' => array('rtf'),

  'text/sgml' => array('sgml', 'sgm'),

  'text/tab-separated-values' => array('tsv'),

  'text/vnd.wap.wml' => array('wml'),

  'text/vnd.wap.wmlscript' => array('wmls'),

  'text/x-setext' => array('etx'),

  'video/mpeg' => array('mpeg','3gp','mp4', 'mpg', 'mpe'),

  'video/quicktime' => array('qt', 'mov'),

  'video/vnd.mpegurl' => array('mxu', 'm4u'),

  'video/x-msvideo' => array('avi'),

  'video/x-sgi-movie' => array('movie'),

  'x-conference/x-cooltalk' => array('ice')

 );
 foreach ($mime_types as $mime_type => $exts)
 {
  if (in_array($ext, $exts))
  {
   return $mime_type;
  }
 }
 return 'text/plain';
}
$id = $_GET['id'];
$error = false;
$error = (!$product->is_product($id)?$products->error:$error);
$error =(!$purchases->is_purchased($_SESSION['uid'],$id)?$purchases->error:$error);
if(!$error){
$file = $product->details($id);
$filepath = $file['file'];
$fname=get_basename($filepath);
if (fopen($filepath,r) || (file_exists($filepath)) ){
if (@filesize($filepath)){
$fsize =filesize($filepath);
}
else
{
$fsize =  get_remote_file_size($filepath); 
}
$ext= get_ext($fname);
$ctype= find_mime_type($ext);
header('Content-Type:'. $ctype );
header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fname);
ob_clean();
$file = fopen($filepath,'r');
ob_end_flush();
fpassthru($file);
set_time_limit(0);
}else{
return  'File Doesn\'t Exist';  } // exist fxn....
}
echo $error;
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify where the corruption is in your opinion. When you pull the file to your server or when the browser actually downloads it? Have you tried `curl` or `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: The corruption definitely occurs when a browser actually downloads a file, the files are fine before and fine if i download manually via ftp and browser ,  I have not tried either of those yet, but certainly will and let you know if successful, Thanks :)

Comment: Just a quick update for anyone who stumbled across this, I managed to get this working ...... I had tried many different variations of certain commands, but it seems i had missed trying with ob_clean() and ob_end_flush() with fopen() , .. It did the trick and as i expected it was a simple fix Thanks for the help Twisty, you poked at my inspiration ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update for anyone who stumbled across this, I managed to get this working ......

I had tried many different variations of certain commands, 
but it seems i had missed trying with ob_clean() and ob_end_flush() with fopen() , .. 
It did the trick and as i expected it was a simple fix

Thanks for the help Twisty, you poked at my inspiration ;)

The corrected and working code has been updated in the OP

Comment: Thanks, corrupt downloads have been plaguing me too.  Just commenting for future reference if I need it again.  Appreciate the fix =)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any code executed after the last line `readfile(FILE_NAME)`

In my case, I had to add `die();` or `exit();` as the last line, because MVC framework continues to render the view after `readfile`